# crash on CPTScatterPlotDelegate in CorePlot

Tags: cocoa, core-plot

I am trying to overlay multiple graphs in one plot and I am getting crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on the CPTScatterPlotDelegate below in class CPTScatterPlot.m

```
-(void)renderAsVectorInContext:(nonnull CGContextRef)context {
    ...
    // Draw line
    if ( theLineStyle ) {
        CGPathRef dataLinePath = [self   newDataLinePathForViewPoints:viewPoints indexRange:viewIndexRange baselineYValue:CPTNAN];

        // Give the delegate a chance to prepare for the drawing.
        id<CPTScatterPlotDelegate> theDelegate = self.delegate;
       ....
    }
    ...
}
```

The Same in CPTLegendDelegate in class CPTPlot.m

```
-(void)drawSwatchForLegend:(nonnull CPTLegend *)legend atIndex:(NSUInteger)idx inRect:(CGRect)rect inContext:(nonnull CGContextRef)context
{
    id<CPTLegendDelegate> theDelegate = (id<CPTLegendDelegate>)self.delegate;
     ...
}
```

I am using CorePlot 2.1, and I have modified the renderInGraphHostingView in file SimpleScatterPlot.m in examples/CorePlotGallery as follows:

```
-(void)renderInGraphHostingView:(nonnull CPTGraphHostingView *)hostingView withTheme:(nullable CPTTheme *)theme animated:(BOOL)animated {
   ...
   static CPTGraph *graph = nil;
   if( initialize ) {
      graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
      ...
   }
   [self addGraph:graph toHostingView:hostingView];
   theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
   ...
}
```

So every time I want to draw a new line of data, I use the same graph.

The problem is random and sometimes program crashes when I draw the second line, sometimes in the third, but it always works fine for the first graph. It also depends on the compilation.
Any ideas?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delegate` property holds a weak reference to the delegate object. Make sure the delegate isn't being deallocated between graph updates.

Comment: Eric, thanks I was accidentally creating multiple copies of the SimpleScatterPlot class every time I was trying to create a new graph.